# Terraform get certs data from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create an "aws_iam_server_certificate", however, rather the storing the file along with the code and passing using "${file(path)}", the file will reside in S3.

I have the below, not sure if the correct approach:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "mycert"{
    bucket = "thisbucket"
    key = "mycoolcertins3.pem"
}
```

I want to them pass to my "aws_iam_server_certificate" creation below:

```
resource "aws_iam_server_certificate" "testcert"{
    name_prefix = "some-cert"
    certificate_body = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.mycert.body}"
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Would the above work, is there a better approach to this?

Following the approach above I get:

```
Error: Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.vault-ui-lb.aws_iam_server_certificate.testcert: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_iam_server_certificate.testcert: Error uploading server certificate, error: MalformedCertificate: Unable to parse certificate. Please ensure the certificate is in PEM format.
```

Regards.

Comment: What happens when you run it? Do you get an error?

Comment: Edited.@ydaetskcoR

Comment: `certificate_body = {$(data.aws_s3_bucket_object.mycert.key)}` looks like it should be `certificate_body = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.mycert.key}"` for it to actually parse properly but you also want the `body` output so probably just `certificate_body = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.mycert.body}"`

Comment: I have tried the suggestion above but get: `Resource 'data.aws_s3_bucket_object.mycert' does not have attribute 'body' for variable`. Most documentation online use the `${file(path)}`. I should probably look into that option @ydaetskcoR

Comment: What is the content type on that S3 object?

Comment: Just saw that Content-Type on s3 was "binary/octet-stream", should probably "text/plain"! @ydaetskcoR

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @ydaetskcoR, I have changed the "Content-Type" of the file (previously "binary/octet-stream") to "text-plain", in S3 under Properties->Metadata and that runs successfully, whether it's a good practice to change the content type of a PEM file to text/plain, I am not entirely sure till someone shouts!